# Wordpress Query for custom post type new addition

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to get a boolean value(true/false) in a php variable if a new post type is added in wordpress admin.

For now I have this code

```
<?php

    $popularpost = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'product','date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '-3days' ) )  ) );
    $v=1; while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();
        if($v >=1){

        $_SESSION["newproduct"] = "newproduct";

    ?>
            <script>
                $( ".shop > a" ).after( "<span>New</span>" );
            </script>

        <?php  }  ?>


<?php   $v++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example below, the list of all products is displayed first.
If posted three days earlier, a new tag will be created next to them

```
 <?php

        $popularpost = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'product') );
        while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

       $post_data = strtotime( get_post( get_the_ID() )->post_date );
       $before_3_days = time() - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60);
       if($post_data >$before_3_days) {
       ?>

                <script>
                    $( ".shop > a" ).after( "<span>New</span>" );
                </script>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```